# Not able to work with peer dependency in react native

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have one react-native app in which I am using "json-schema-rules" library. Now I have also created one library which is getting used in my react-native app like this "file:../custom_library" in package.json.

Now to resolve the version conflict, I decided to use "json-schema-rules" as a peer dependency in my custom library. So, the package.json is like this

Package.json of my react-native app:
`{
  "dependencies": {
    "json-rules-engine": "^2.3.0",
    "custom_library": "file:../custom_library"
}
}`

package.json of my custom_library:`{
  "peerDependencies": {
     "json-schema-rules": "^2.3.0"
}
}`

Now the problem is, whenever I am using metro bundler, I get an error
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `json-rules-engine`
json-rules-engine could not be found within the project.

This is the case when I am using it in peerDependencies, I do not get any error if I use this library in dependencies.

Please help.

Comment: You can try to add a babel alias using the npm package `babel-plugin-module-resolver` so that when metro goes looking for cutsom_library/json-schema-rules it finds the package inside your react-native app.

Comment: I don't know whether I understood what you said, but I have included my custom library in metro.config.js to watch for extraNodemodules. 
Here is the file: https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/7c0c8a03a62c5ecba0b8247aec0dbd2d

But I think, the problem is, I have json-schema-rules as peerDependencies in custom_library and when I do npm install it doesn't install json-schema-rules. And when my app project looks extra node modules in custum_library, it notices that json-schema-rules is being used in code of custom_library but it's not there in node modules

Comment: peerDependency means that it will not be installed for the library, but will be asked from the project that that library will be used at.
so if I understood correctly, I think you need to add `json-schema-rules` as a dependency in your app, this way when you add your the library, the library will find it installed already for it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an alias for the module in your project's babel config.

This means that when your custom packages tries to import "json-rules-engine" it will get served the version from the main app.

First install 'babel-plugin-module-resolver' then configure the alias in "module-resolver"

babel.config.js

```js
const config = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        root: ["./src"],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ios.js", ".android.js"], 
        alias: {
          "json-rules-engine": require.resolve("json-rules-engine") 
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
module.exports = config;
```